# why doesn't the q-learning function converge in openai mountain car

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

**UPDATE 1:** revised the greedy epsilon policy as the number of episodes it took before making epsilon a very less quantity were very less. i have updated the code.

the new problem is after fully training it should not deviate much but it picks up wrong values and instantly diverges is epsilon becomes small

---

i have been working on [openai gym](https://gym.openai.com/) platform for quite sometime now as my goal to learn more about reinforcement learning. i have successfully implemented double deep-q learning(DQN) with prioritized experience replay(PER) with help of stack overflow user @sajad. On cart-pole problem and received  very good success rate with careful hyper-parameter tuning. this is so far the best algorithm i have learned but whatever i do i cannot seem to get this work on mountain car problem where the reward always keeps on -200 for episodes. i have looked into my code and from [various tutorials](https://jaromiru.com/2016/11/07/lets-make-a-dqn-double-learning-and-prioritized-experience-replay/) i think my memory implementation is correct.

neither of the algorithms from basic DQN to DQN with PER seems to work.

it would be helpful if i would get some help in debugging the code or any other implementation changes which might be causing it not to converge

here is my implementation: all parameters have usual names

```
    # implemented using sum_tree

import os
import random

import gym
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from memory import Memory

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0")
env.reset()
model_save_path = "C:/Users/sanka/codes/mountain car openai/mc_save"


class dqn(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = 0
        self.batch_size = 64
        self.episodes = 20000
        self.input_size = env.observation_space.sample().size
        self.output_size = env.action_space.n
        self.gamma = 0.99
        self.epsilon = 1.0
        self.step = 0
        self.learning_rate = 0.0001
        self.lambda1 = 0.001
        self.initial_epsilon = self.epsilon
        self.final_epsilon = 0.01
        self.weights = {}
        self.biases = {}
        self.target_weights = {}
        self.target_biases = {}
        self.create_nn()
        self.create_training_network()
        self.max_size = 10000
        self.memory = Memory(size=self.max_size)
        self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()

    def create_nn(self):

        s1 = {1: [self.input_size, 30], 2: [30, 100], 3: [100, 30], 4: [30, self.output_size]}
        s2 = {1: [30], 2: [100], 3: [30], 4: [self.output_size]}
        for i in s1:
            self.weights[i] = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(s1[i]), name='w{0}'.format(i))
            self.biases[i] = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(s2[i]), name='b{0}'.format(i))
            self.target_weights[i] = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(s1[i]), name='tw{0}'.format(i))
            self.target_biases[i] = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(s2[i]), name='tb{0}'.format(i))

    def feed_forward(self, z):
        q = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(z, self.weights[1]) + self.biases[1])
        for i in range(2, len(self.weights), 1):
            q = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(q, self.weights[i]) + self.biases[i])
        q = tf.matmul(q, self.weights[len(self.weights)]) + self.biases[len(self.biases)]
        return q

    def feed_forward_target(self, z):
        q = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(z, self.target_weights[1]) + self.target_biases[1])
        for i in range(2, len(self.weights), 1):
            q = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(q, self.target_weights[i]) + self.target_biases[i])
        q = tf.matmul(q, self.target_weights[len(self.weights)]) + self.target_biases[len(self.weights)]
        return q

    def create_training_network(self):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.input_size])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
        self.a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.output_size])
        self.q_value = self.feed_forward(self.x)
        self.q_value_target = self.feed_forward_target(self.x)
        self.output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(self.q_value, self.a), reduction_indices=1)
        self.action = tf.argmax(self.q_value, 1)
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.output - self.y))
        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)

    def append_to_memory(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        one_hot_action = np.zeros(self.output_size)
        one_hot_action[action] = 1.0
        prob = (abs(reward) + .01) ** 0.6
        self.memory.append(prob, (state, one_hot_action, reward, next_state, done))
        if self.memory.current_size >= self.memory.size:
            self.step += 1
            # self.epsilon = self.final_epsilon + (self.initial_epsilon - self.final_epsilon) * np.exp(
            #    -self.lambda1 * (self.step / 200))
            self.epsilon = max(self.initial_epsilon - (self.step / 200) * self.lambda1, self.final_epsilon)
            if (self.flag == 0):
                print("started training")
                self.flag = 1
            self.train()

    def get_reward(self, q1, q2, reward, done):
        if done:
            return reward
        else:
            return reward + self.gamma * q2[np.argmax(q1)]

    def train(self):
        index, sample = self.memory.sample(self.batch_size)
        train_x = [i[0] for i in sample]
        action = [i[1] for i in sample]
        reward = [i[2] for i in sample]
        next_state = [i[3] for i in sample]
        train_y = []
        q = self.sess.run(self.q_value, feed_dict={self.x: np.array(train_x)})
        q_1 = self.sess.run(self.q_value, feed_dict={self.x: np.array(next_state)})
        q_next = self.sess.run(self.q_value_target, feed_dict={self.x: np.array(next_state)})
        for i in range(len(reward)):
            train_y.append(self.get_reward(q_1[i], q_next[i], reward[i], sample[i][4]))
        train_y = np.array(train_y)
        train_x = np.array(train_x)
        action = np.array(action)
        self.sess.run(self.optimizer, feed_dict={self.x: train_x, self.y: train_y, self.a: action})
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            error = abs(np.max(q[i]) - train_y[i])
            self.memory.update(index[i], (error + 0.01) ** 0.6)
            # return loss

    def copy_variables(self):
        for i in range(1, len(self.weights) + 1, 1):
            self.sess.run(self.target_weights[i].assign(self.weights[i]))
            self.sess.run(self.target_biases[i].assign(self.biases[i]))

    def save(self):
        self.saver.save(self.sess, model_save_path)
        print("model saved")


def main():
    obj = dqn()
    for e in range(obj.episodes):
        p = env.reset()
        for i in range(500):
            # obj.step += 1
            ac = obj.sess.run(obj.action, feed_dict={obj.x: np.array([p])})[0]
            if np.random.rand() < obj.epsilon:
                ac = random.randint(0, obj.output_size - 1)

            obs, rew, done, _ = env.step(ac)
            obj.append_to_memory(p, ac, rew, obs, done)
            p = obs
            if done:
                break
            if obj.step % 1000 == 0 and obj.flag == 1:
                obj.copy_variables()
        # print("episode {0} completed with loss: {1}".format(e, total_loss))

        if e % 100 == 0:
            print("episodes {0} completed".format(e), )
            av = []
            for f in range(10):
                p = env.reset()
                r = 0
                for i in range(200):
                    ac = obj.sess.run(obj.action, feed_dict={obj.x: np.array([p])})[0]
                    p, rew, done, _ = env.step(ac)
                    r += rew
                    if done:
                        break
                av.append(r)
            print("average score is {0}".format(np.average(np.array(av))))
            obj.save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

for reference here is the implementation of the memory implemented as separate module:

```
import numpy as np
import random


class Memory(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.data = np.zeros(size, dtype=object)
        self.tree = np.zeros(2 * size - 1, dtype=np.float32)
        self.current_size = 0
        self.last = 0

    def append(self, p, data):
        self.current_size = min(self.current_size + 1, self.size)
        cur = self.last + self.size - 1
        self.update_at_index(cur, p - self.tree[cur])
        self.data[self.last] = data
        self.last += 1
        if self.last >= self.size:
            self.last = 0

    def update(self, index, p):
        self.update_at_index(index, p - self.tree[index])

    def update_at_index(self, index, change):
        while (index >= 0):
            self.tree[index] += change
            index = (index - 1) // 2

    def get(self, index, s):
        left = index * 2 + 1
        if (left >= self.size):
            return (index, self.data[index + 1 - self.size])
        if (self.tree[left] >= s):
            return self.get(left, s)
        else:
            right = left + 1
            return self.get(right, s - self.tree[left])

    def sample(self, n):
        av_sum = self.tree[0] / n
        l = []
        m = []
        for i in range(n):
            min_sum = av_sum * i
            max_sum = av_sum * (i + 1)
            s = random.uniform(min_sum, max_sum)
            x = self.get(0, s)
            l.append(x[0])
            m.append(x[1])
        return l, m
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I worked on a continuous version of montain car (the one that is now in openai gym) and solved it with DDPG, and during my experiments I found that if no reward is achieved during the few first episodes, it learns to do nothing. So here it is an exploration issue, maybe you could let it do random actions for some episodes, before starting to learn. 
Or find a way to reward exploration. (for example it worked great for me when I gave reward for never seen observations).

Comment: yes i did let it explore fully for initial 50 episodes(as my memory is 10000) and after that i started decreasing epsilon at exponential rate and start to learn. during my initial attempts with random sampling it did converge a little but then again falls into traps. with PER it never does converge even little even 4000 episodes. i also tried decreasing rate at which epsilon decreases. but i will try your reward method to look if it works

Comment: you were right, it was exploration issues. so i updated my number of times i was using random values. so it starts to converge but then after my epsilon becomes very less it starts to diverge again. couldn't find a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

I tried simple DQN without prioritized experience replay on MountainCar problem, and it converges well. I think the problem might lie in these two aspects:

1) The original state representation is only of 4-dimension, which makes many different states Indistinguishable. So I utilized the following codes (which is from some other people's blog) to extract some features for the state representation which maximizes the difference between states.

```
class Featurize_state():
def __init__(self, env, no_change = False):
    self.no_change = no_change
    if no_change == True:
        self.After_featurize_state_dim = env.observation_space.shape[0]
        return 

    # to accumulate experiences  
    observation_examples = np.array([env.observation_space.sample() for x in range(10000)])
    # calculate empirical mean and std deviation
    self.scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()
    self.scaler.fit(observation_examples)

    # Used to converte a state to a featurizes represenation.
    # use RBF kernels with different variances to cover different parts of the space
    self.featurizer = sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion([
    ("rbf1", RBFSampler(gamma=5.0, n_components=50)),
    ("rbf2", RBFSampler(gamma=2.0, n_components=100))
    #("rbf3", RBFSampler(gamma=1.0, n_components=100)),
    #("rbf4", RBFSampler(gamma=0.5, n_components=100))
    ])
    self.featurizer.fit(observation_examples)
    self.After_featurize_state_dim = 150

def get_featurized_state_dim(self):
    return self.After_featurize_state_dim

def transfer(self, state):
    if self.no_change:
        return state

    #scaled = self.scaler.transform([state])
    featurized = self.featurizer.transform([state])
    return featurized[0]
    #return state
```

2) When the reward is sparse (since no reward is given until you reach the target), do not use too many layers in your neural network. The more complicated the learning model, the more samples that carry information (reward) it needs to learn. Just using one layer with relu combined with state featurization works really well for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "indistinguishable" ? The 4 dimensions of the states fully describe it. There is no hidden variable, and with a given state and action couple, the next state is fully deterministic. You can change representation, but it will not add any information.

Answer (score -3):

Additional to what has been said. I suggest you two more aspects that worked for me.

1. Create a custom reward to speed up convergence of the Q-learning. Adding rewards for encouraging momentum of the car worked for me.
2. Try skipping frames. As stated in [DeepMind DQN Nature paper](https://deepmind.com/research/publications/human-level-control-through-deep-reinforcement-learning/) about frame-skipping "the agent sees and selects actions on every kth frame instead of every frame". In the case of the mountain car problem, it means that you could repeat the same action for the next kth states. For me repeating the same action, every 4 states worked.

Comment: By giving additional reward you change the MDP to another one. You then solve a different (and simpler) problem.